# ?android:attr/selectableItemBackground

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

when writing my android app i used

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

I tried looking for attr.xml file that would be containing the source but i could not find it. Any ideas please on where i can find it. I found one attr.xml in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-13\data\res\values

but it did not have the attribute mentioned above. Can anyone lead me where I can find the xml resource with the attribute above?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm not that experienced with Android, but I think you can find what you're looking for in *"data\res\values\themes.xml"*.

If you search in that file for *"selectableItemBackground"*, you should find the following:

```
<style name="Theme">
...
        <item name="selectableItemBackground">@android:drawable/item_background</item>
...
</style>
```

You'll also find respective entries for *Theme.Holo.Light* and *Theme.Holo*.  The *"item_background"*, *"item_background_holo_light"*, and *"item_background_holo_dark"* drawables would be located in the *"data\res\drawable"* folder.

Hope that helps!

Comment: And if you are using your own drawable, remember to remove the "android:" attribute.

Comment: full path for me on Windows was:
``C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-34\data\res\values\themes``