# Is there a default selector for the RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with items in it. If i click on a item, it does not give any feedback. The backgorund does not get slightly darker like in a listview. This mean I don't know I pressed the item. Is there some default selector available or should I create my own?

Comment: it is "?attr/selectableItemBackground"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19780767/3209739
It gives ripple effect. So you can easily realise that you pressed an item.

Answer (score 0):

For RecyclerView there is no such parameter as selector in ListView. In Material Theme there are some selectors.  I used following attribute *attr/listChoiceBackgroundIndicator*

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
     android:foreground="?attr/listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">
```

It can be set as android:background.